# Java Mysql Tunnel Communications Error

Tags: java, mysql, jsch, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect to a remote server using `JSch`, the connection seems to be working, it is just that mysql is throwing an error when it is trying to connect:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I have checked the connection string, and it seems to be correct, but why isn't mysql connecting? It connects fine to other database that use a username/password but when I add the SSH tunnel it throws the above error.

Here is the Forward:

```
lport: 3308, rhost: 127.0.0.1, rport: 3306
```

Here is the output of my connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3308/?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

Here is how I am connecting:

```
// MySQL Connection Strings
ResultSet info = sql.getConnectionInfo(connectionName);
String host = info.getString("host");
String user = info.getString("user");
String pass = info.getString("pass");
String port = info.getString("port");

// SSH Connection String
ResultSet sshInfo = sql.getSSHSettings(connectionName);
if(sshInfo.next()){
    String sshHost = sshInfo.getString("sshHost");
    String sshPort = sshInfo.getString("sshPort");
    String sshLPort = sshInfo.getString("sshLPort");
    String sshUser = sshInfo.getString("sshUser");
    String sshPass = sshInfo.getString("sshPass");
    String sshPPK = sshInfo.getString("sshPrivateKey");
    JSch ssh = new JSch();
    try{
        if(!sshPPK.equals("")){
            ssh.addIdentity(sshPPK);
        }
        Session session = ssh.getSession(sshUser, sshHost, Integer.parseInt(sshPort));
        session.setPassword(sshPass);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.connect();
        session.setTimeout(4);
        String rhost = "127.0.0.1";
        int assignedPort = session.setPortForwardingL(Integer.parseInt(sshLPort), rhost, Integer.parseInt(port));
        System.out.println(rhost + ":" + assignedPort + " -> " + sshHost + ":" + port);
        // Set MySQL port to the tunnel port and the host to localhost
        host = rhost;
        port = String.valueOf(assignedPort);
    }catch(JSchException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
MysqlWrapper mysqlConn = new MysqlWrapper(host, user, pass, port);
```

Here is how I am connection to MySQL:

```
public void connect(){
    try{
        if(conn != null){
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(url);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    }catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(Mysql.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2840358/1391249, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2985169/1391249, http://stackoverflow.com/q/6865538/1391249

Comment: I can connect to the same server/database using other applications with the same credentials.

Comment: I got it! It was because I had a `setTimeout`...